# Calling modelToView() method freezes Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, deadlock, freeze

I am creating a Transliterating tool in Java. It's almost complete.
But, when I type so fast the GUI freezes.

So, I debugged the application to pinpoint the command where it is happening.

The call to method `JTextField.modelToView(pos)` causes this, which further calls `TextUI.modelToView(JTextComponent c, int pos)`.

It appears, this method first acquires lock on text component's document by calling `AbstractDocument::readLock()` method, whose source code is:

```
public synchronized final void readLock() {
    try {
        while (currWriter != null) {
            if (currWriter == Thread.currentThread()) {
                // writer has full read access.... may try to acquire
                // lock in notification
                return;
            }
            wait();
        }
        numReaders += 1;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new Error("Interrupted attempt to aquire read lock");
    }
}
```

Which calls `wait()` if current thread is not the writer thread.

But, I am only mutating document when space key is pressed, which I believe happens in EDT. And, `Swing` would also be mutating it in EDT. Also, I am calling `JTextField.modelToView(pos)` when `DocumentListener.insertUpdate(DocumentEvent)` is invoked.

Then, what is the reason, the application freezes!

Here are the screenshots:

The application screenshot
[image]

When Application freezes
[image]

If I minimize and maximize the window
[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Ok, let me see, If I can reproduce the problem using a small piece of code!

Comment: "*which I believe happens in EDT*" This can be confirmed by printing the boolean method `EventQueue.isDispatchThread()`

Comment: Yes, it is true everytime.

Comment: I have created the small snapshot of my code, but it is not reproducing the problem. What do I do now?

Comment: Is there any alternate way to get caret position on screen? As it is confirmed that `JTextField.modelToView(pos)` is causing this freeze!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am calling JTextField.modelToView(pos) when DocumentListener.insertUpdate(DocumentEvent) is invoked.

The Document has not been updated completely when the DocumentEvent is fired. Wrap your code in the DocumentListener in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. This should cause your event code to be executed after the Document has finished updating itself.

Comment: Ok, let me try it. But, I read it somewhere that these methods are fired after document has been updated! Isn't it true always?